# Classes where boys work with their hands

Tags: translation

There are special kind of classes in Soviet and now Russian schools where boys work with their hands, building some stuff, e. g. starling-houses.

There are also classes for girls, where they learn how to cook and sew.

How should I name that subject and teachers who teach that?

Comment: If you find the answer to your question, post it as an answer (which I see you did, then deleted) instead of editing it into your question. This way you can accept the answer and it can be voted on.

Comment: It's not an answer. What about girls?

Comment: While I think there's traditional types of classes that used to be split by gender, there's no longer a formal split and assignment of skill/craft classes based on sex or gender in any predominantly English-speaking area I know of. I'd be careful with the potential to offend by assuming that some skills are for one gender or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, the "boys'" class is called *[shop](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shop+class)* or *shop class*. The "girls'" class is called [*home economics* or *home ec*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_economics). In both cases, the teachers are referred to as *[class name] teacher*. I can't speak to other regions.

These are long standing general and colloquial names for these classes. Frequently they are called something else, as these monikers are often considered "politically incorrect".

Comment: Additionally, instruction in a particular industrial art can be added to the name— *metal shop*, *auto shop*, and so on: *We made a birdhouse in wood shop*. Related is *voc ed* (vocational education), which is intended to introduce students to a manual trade.

Comment: In my kids' school, they are still called "shop" and "home ec". They just no longer say that shop is for boys and home ec is for girls. In real life, of course, few girls sing up for metal shop and even fewer boys sign up for home ec. But you're not supposed to say this out loud, or if you do, you're supposed to say how terrible it is and how we must work to encourage more cross-over. :-)

Answer (score 1):

While "shop" is often used (particularly for a woodworking class), a more formal term is [industrial arts](http://www.onelook.com/?w=industrial+arts&ls=a). Some high schools have an array of industrial arts courses available, such as woodworking, electricity, and small engine repair.

Home economics is having an identity crisis of sorts, sometimes getting a more modern name like *family and consumer science*. There's an interesting [article](http://www.oatfacs.org/Evolution%20of%20Home%20Economics.html) about this transition that mentions:

> *Home ec has not disappeared, it's changed, evolving into classes focusing on child development, nutrition, family health, food service and hospitality. It hasn't been lost as much as translated. In 1994, the name of the course in most of the country was officially changed from Home Economics to Family and Consumer Sciences, or FCS, in an effort to dispel the impression that home ec was about teaching girls how to be housewives*.

Answer (score -1):

The proper term for the boys classes should be "handicrafts".